# Is it possible to create a div element with jquery onclick of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a navigation list.  The effect I am looking for is when the user clicks on a link, an accordion style div is built and displayed by jQuery.  Then if the user clicks the same screen, the  is deleted from the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some cod that will create an DIV if it is not already there, load it with some HTML from the URL contained in a link's HREF attribute, then turn it into an accordion.  If the DIV already exists, it removes it.

```
$('.navLink').click( function() {
   var accordion_id = 'accordion_' + this.id;
   var accordion = $('#' + accordion_id);
   if (accordion.length > 0) {
      accodion.remove();
   }
   else {
      $('<div id="' + accordion_id + '"></div>')
           .appendTo('#someDiv')
           .load( $(this).attr('href') )
           .accordion();
   }
   return false; // cancel default action of link
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm quite sure that this is possible. It looks like there may be plugins and third-party tools out there that can help you with this task. This one looks promising: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/